# How to capture "*" as argument to bash function and use in a comparison

Tags: regex, bash, wildcard, rm

I want to have bash run `rm -i *` if I type `rm *` but otherwise run regular `rm`. Importantly, I don't want to run `rm -i` every time I use a wildcard such as `rm part*`. Here is as far as I could come up with:

```
rm ()
{
    if [ "$1" == "*" ]; then
        rm -i *
    else
        rm $1
    fi
}
```

But I know this will fail. I know that the comparison I want is to `^*$`, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: By the time your `rm` function is executed the `*` has already been expanded.

Comment: The problem is that `rm` doesn't get `*` as an argument; it gets the long list of files that the shell expands `*` to as arguments.

Comment: GNU `rm` has a `-I` option that only prompts you if removing more than 3 files.

Comment: btw, `==` isn't actually guaranteed to work inside `[ ]`, which conforms with POSIX test; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, which specifies `=` (only one character) as the string comparison operator. Now, bash extends the standard by making `==` available as an option, but if you want to be explicit that you're depending on bash extensions, better to use `[[ ]]` instead.

Comment: Yup, I need to work on my shell scripting consistency. Still kind of a noob/hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's **literally impossible** to know if your command was called with a wildcard without the cooperation of your shell.

When you invoke `rm *` (like any other command), the `*` is replaced with a list of filenames *before invocation*. Thus, when inside the command, the information that it was given a wildcard no longer exists: `$1`, `$2`, etc. have been replaced with a list of names that the wildcard expanded to.

---

That said, since we're a shell function, the cooperation of our shell is actually available:

```
rm() {
  local cmd
  read -r _ cmd < <(HISTTIMEFORMAT=''; history 1)
  if [[ $cmd = "rm *" ]]; then
    command rm -i "$@"
  else
    command rm "$@"
  fi
}
```

---

How does this work?

- `history 1` returns the most recent command in the shell's history (preceded by a number).
- `read -r _ cmd` reads that number into the variable `_`, and the rest of the command line into the variable `cmd`
- `[[ $cmd = "rm *" ]]` compares the command against that precise string
- `command rm ...` runs the *external* `rm` command, avoiding recursion back to our function again.

Comment: This might not work for some cases. I've `export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T] "` in my shell and it fails. Probably condition can change to `[[ $cmd == *"rm *" ]]`

Comment: No I didn't mean that. In the current form this function didn't run `rm -i ...` because I had `export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T] "` in my `.bashrc` which caused `history 1` to output `49370  [2016-07-29 15:42:52] rm *`. That's why I suggested `[[ $cmd == *"rm *" ]]` might work

Comment: *facepalm* -- I missed that `*"rm *"` is anchored on the end. Yup, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @anubhava, ...though on consideration, I think just clearing `HISTTIMEFORMAT` in the subshell is the simpler change.

Comment: Yes indeed unsetting `HISTTIMEFORMAT` did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't know if there is a wildcard, why not check the number of arguments?

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm () {
    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
       echo command rm -i "$@"
    else
       echo command rm "$@"
    fi
}
rm a b c
rm a
```

Comment: ...but you don't know if you're getting `a` because that's what `*` evaluates to, or `a` because that's what the user passed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: That's true. But I think the use case is to warn if multiple files are going to be deleted, so it may be a valid alternative for the OP.

Comment: I totally love the elegance of the solution. It actually gets to the heart of the matter -- preventing me from removing more than one file (or whatever number I put in there). But I think it is overall safer to actually capture the command. Great job though!

Comment: The OP said "Importantly, I don't want to run `rm -i` every time I use a wildcard such as `rm part*`".